# Can I Set Pixel Preview as the Default view when opening files in Illustrator CC?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Sorry if this has been asked, i googled for quite a bit and i actually couldnt find much of anything about pixel preview.

I'm trying to open a couple hundred files in illustrator at once, and using a keyboard shortcut to fit artboard to the artwork. It runs just fine surprisingly even if it eats up 8-10+ gb of memory; just trying to get this running as fast as possible!

Is there a way to set the default view to pixel or even outline when i open files? it defaults to GPU preview, or CPU preview if i disable GPU preview in prefs.

Specs:

- i5-2500k @ 4.3ghz (stock voltage)
- GTX 780 classified @ stock (performance mode, not power saving mode)
- 16gb @ 1600mhz 450gb SSD (artwork and program both on ssd)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can record an action to do all three steps, open the files, switch to pixel preview and fit artboard to artwork bounds...then you can batch the action to open a bunch of files in a folder.

Comment: hmmm...i understand how to batch in photoshop. i wasn't aware there were batch jobs in illustrator i was only aware of scripts. sigh...right in front of me. for future reference anybody: Batch is located in the panel menu of the Actions window.

Comment: Another FYI for people that also did not know this. had i  known i would have actually made actions like i use in photoshop. If you use the action panel menu...you can insert Menu items. i could not record a keyboard shortcut or the artboard tool's 'fit to artwork bounds' option. panel menu's 'insert menu item' worked, however. I clicked 'insert menu item' and then typed in the word 'fit' and pressed find and scrolled down to 'fit to artwork bounds'. Thanks Carlos!

Comment: You're welcome, sorry I should have mentioned about using "Insert Menu Item"